# Add NuGet Packages Folder to Solution File?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, package, solution, ankhsvn

Nuget puts the package in my root folder(in my case my trunk folder). I am wondering is there a way to let VS 2010 know about this folder? I am using ankh svn to do my commuting so it would be really nice to have it in my solution so when I add a reference I can commit it from VS 2010 and not have to go to my trunk and manually do it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this currently is by using the Working Copy Explorer (View -> Working Copy Explorer). From here you can browse your solution folder, and add the reference.

I added the idea to enhance this to the [AnkhSVN feedback forum](http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-ankhsvn-general/suggestions/1420009-enable-svn-add-ing-references), please go vote :-)

Comment: this will work fine, the issue is that you have to manual do it and when you add other packages you need to do it again.  When in a team the other developers will no have the files pulled from source control automatically.  So for a single dev i would agree with answer.

Comment: @SimonThompson That's not true, adding it is manual, but only needs to be done by one person that adds the reference. The rest is automatic.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.  Be sure to check out Leniel Macaferi's answer for the preferred method.

Answer (score 23):

You may be interested in reading this NuGet doc:

[Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)

Comment: Yep. Been using this since it came out. Happy they came up with this solution as it is even better than committing the .dlls.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Just what I was looking for! :)

Comment: That's very nice. Does that still work if the build is done by NAnt?

Comment: @daveL Unfortunately I don't know if this is possible with `NAnt`. You'd better ask another question here on StackOverflow (mentioning this one)... I'm sure someone versed with `NAnt` will reply. :)

Answer (score 9):

You should consider 'don't commit packages workflow'. It is much more mature solution:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html

Comment: I think this is now made obsolete by Leniel Macaferi's answer.

Comment: true, but the question dates back to 2011, when there wa no such a mechanism :)

Answer (score 7):

You can add the packages directory as a web project.  I use TFS so the only issue is after adding a package I need to include these files to the source control but at least there visible...

Comment: Agree should be an official way , it's like they forgot :-)

Comment: I got build errors initially doing this. Remember to remove the "web site" from the list of projects to build. Then works like a charm.