# Add NuGet package by default?

Tags: visual-studio, automation, nuget, visual-studio-2013

We use the StyleCop.MSBuild NuGet package here to check our coding style guidelines. At the moment we add this package manually to every new project, which can be forgotten very easily.

**Is there a way to add the package automatically to every new project?**

Or can you at least "add a package to the solution" so it is added to every project in that solution?

P.S.: We also use TFS builds with a custom template - so an option which adds the package during build would also be a valid option...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding a reference to your solution through "Working Copy Explorer".

This [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777563/add-nuget-packages-folder-to-solution-file) may help you